# Find element and replace in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

i am in a bit of a jam here, i am trying to find all div elements that are inside of another div container and then replace the matches with a new div using just javascript.

Here is a description:

I have these divs

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="oldclass">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="oldclass">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="oldclass">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="oldclass">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="oldclass">latency</div>
</div>
```

And what i want to achieve is this

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="newclass1">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="newclass2">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="newclass1">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="newclass2">latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div>latency</div>
    <div class="newclass1">latency</div>
</div>
```

But i am having a really hard time with this, i already used childNodes, .match(), replace(), etc etc

Any help is very much appreciated and thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code, i select all div nodes from the document and loop through them.
If the classname of the node equals "oldclass", rename the classname to "newclass".

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
firstChanged = false;
for(i=0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
  if(elements[i].className == "oldclass")
  {
    elements[i].className = (firstChanged) ? "newclass2" : "newclass1";
    firstChanged = !firstChanged;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** The firstChanged boolean checks whether the script has come to the point of changing the first matching div.

Comment: You needn't set an `elSequence` variable. Just test the result of `i % 2`, where `1` means it's odd and `0` means it's even. You could replace the `+ elSequence` with `+ (i % 2 ? 1 : 2)`.

Comment: Thanks @Delan, i modified the script

Comment: On your example, instead of 1 and 2, is it possible to use text? Something like "newclass left" and "newclass right"

Comment: @user524965, yes. You can use strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i wanted! Thank you very much and to the others that answered too!

Comment: Actually i am running in a bit of a problem here, while this method works with the presented example, when i implement in my html code, it has more divs inbetween, thus changing the actually [i] number, which causes for it to allways be 1, so the actual class never changes, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide a more precise situation then ?

Comment: I have edited it, as you can see, just by having another div number, the code won't work correctly for the entire div, and i used a fixed number of divs inbetween, the actual template generates more. Isn't there anyway to check the previous used [i] and generate a diferent one?

Comment: EDIT: provided a more robust solution for the divs inbetween.

Comment: I assume that the change of class is depending on the div[i] position, which does not work for me cause every div[i] position is returning 1 on i%2, is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: I can see that it is retrieving different values with alert((firstChanged)?2:1)); but for some reason it is not changing the class, it appears as if it is actually removing the entire class. Shouldnt it be creating new classes named "newclass1" and "newclass2"?

Comment: Finally got it working, the 2:1 should actually be "newclass1":"newclass2" in the firstchange parameter, thank you very much for your time and patient and guide, i now understand a bit more of javascript!

Comment: Okay, thanks for mentioning that, i updated the script. Glad I could help !

Answer (score 3):

Why not try using jQuery? With jQuery you can easily do it as follows:

```
$("div.oldclass:even").addClass("newclass1");
$("div.oldclass:odd").addClass("newclass2");
```

This will add "newclass1" to all even indexed DIVs with "oldclass" as CSS class, and "newclass2" to all odd indexed DIVs with "oldclass" as CSS class.

Comment: A few of the answers posted are quite long, but my answer takes advantage of some modern JavaScript features that make it quite small without the need for jQuery.

Comment: I don't understand why more people DON'T use jQuery or similar JavaScript libraries. They make tasks such as the OP very simple.

Answer (score 1):

First, do

```
nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('oldclass');
```

or

```
nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.oldclass');
```

That is a NodeList which can be accessed similarly to an array, then, do what you need to do.

I'm not sure if you're asking to change the CSS class name, or if you're asking to replace the div completely, and if so, where from.

Copy the NodeList to a static array first:

```
nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
```

We don't want `nodes` to be a `NodeList` as these are live and can have unpredictable results when we're modifying them.

**If you want to replace the selected elements with new ones,**

```
nodes[i].parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, nodes[i]);
```

**If you want to change the class names, like in your example, do the first two lines then this:**

```
nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
    node.className = 'newclass' + (i % 2 ? 1 : 2);
});
```

**I'm not quite clear on your question (the intent of your question and your example differ) so I've made suggestions for both possible intents.**

Comment: note that document.getElementsByClassName and document.querySelectorAll won't work in ie, so this solution would work only in Gecko and Webkit browsers

Comment: document.querySelectorAll works in IE8+ too, if he runs in IE8+-mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do
Javascript Only

```
//Select the container  
var div = document.getElementById("container");  
//find all div child with class = oldclass  
var divs = div.getElementsByClassName("oldclass");  
//then replace it  
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)  
{  
    if(i % 2)  
        divs[i].className = "newclass1";  
    else  
        divs[i].className = "newclass2";  
}
`  
//Using Jquery:  
`$("#container div.oldclass").each(function(i){  
        $(this).removeClass("oldclass").addClass("newclass" + (i % 2 ? 1 : 2));  
});
```

Comment: `i % 2` being `true` means that the number is odd, and odd numbers are `newclass1`, so you may want to flip the class names around.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```
var arr = $("#container").children(".oldclass");
var classname = "newclass1";
for(var i=oi<arr.length;i++) {
 $(arr[i]).attr("class",classname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this fiddle that uses jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/Vk687/

Comment: Just a hint, you can use `.classname` instead of `[class=classname]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you using jQuery, you can use .each() function like this:

```
jQuery(".oldclass").each(function(index, domEle) {
    domEle.className = "newclass" + (index%2+1);
});
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/Achilleterzo/79kfF/

Comment: This does not match the requested solution, as there is a need for alternating classnames.

Comment: I forgot to change "div" to ".class", but isn't wrong in fiddle. I correct it